# how to use order by delegable function for large data set in power apps gallery

Tags: powerapps

I'm having a problem with delegation. I have used SortByColumns function for the list in power apps gallery but its showing only 2000 items out of 30000.

For example, I'm using the following formula to filter the list data FIN columns order by ascending :

```
SortByColumns( Search(Filter('Patient Information', varCurrentRenderingProvider = 'Rendering Provider'.DisplayName),TextSearchPatient.Text,"FIN"), "FIN")
```

there is dataset limit, so is there another way to overcome this issue?